# ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported. ubuntu2004 docker

Tags: docker, selenium-chromedriver, cypress

I am running npx cypress run 'path/to/file.js' --browser chrome inside ubuntu2004 docker container and getting the following error message.
'ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported'

This is how I'm installing chrome-browser and seems to be working.

```
# Install chromium
RUN apt install chromium-browser -y

RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

## Cypress
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 
RUN apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb
```

has anybody faced this issue or know what the fix is?

Comment: What version Cypress are you using?

Comment: cypress version 10.11.0

Comment: Could you try 10.8 or 10.6? I suspect it’s a latest release issue

Comment: I had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Cypress on Ubuntu in Github Actions, and am also seeing this warning. However, I've noticed it actually doesn't cause any real issues for me. If you're experiencing issues, it could be worth checking if something else is causing it rather than this.

That said, if someone else could shed some light on this message and what it means, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I logged Cypress issue https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25357 to report this problem when Cypress is run under GitHub Actions.

The workaround is to add

```yml
env:
  ELECTRON_EXTRA_LAUNCH_ARGS: '--disable-gpu'
```

to the GitHub Actions workflow. (This does not work when using Electron as a browser - despite the name of the environment variable.)

The problem seems to be caused by a lack of DRI3 support (Direct Rendering Infrastructure 3) in [Xvfb](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) (virtual framebuffer X server for X Version 11).